# update sql query in for loop but it does not update my db table and did not get any error

Tags: php, mysql

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','','govtpoly');

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $ex="";
    $tpannounce = array();
    $company = array();
    $branch = array();
    $start = array();
    $end = array();
    $tpavanue = array();
    $documents = array();
    $date = array();
    array_push($tpannounce,mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tpasub']));
    array_push($company,mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comname']));
    array_push($branch,mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['branch']));
    $tpasdate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tpasdate']);
    $tpastime = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tpastime']);    
    $tpaedate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tpaedate']);
    $tpaetime = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tpaetime']);
    array_push($tpavanue,mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tpavanue']));

    $start1=$tpasdate." at ".$tpastime."O'clock";
    $end1=$tpaedate." at ".$tpaetime."O'clock";
    $date1 = date("y/m/d");
    array_push($start,$start1);
    array_push($end,$end1);
    array_push($date,$date1);
    mysql_select_db('govtpoly');
    $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM placement";
    mysql_select_db('govtpoly');
    $rs=mysql_query($sql4);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        array_push($tpannounce,$row['placement_subject']);
        array_push($company,$row['company']);
        array_push($branch,$row['branches']);
        array_push($start,$row['start_on']);
        array_push($end,$row['end_on']);
        array_push($tpavanue,$row['vanue']);
        array_push($documents,$row['documents']);
        array_push($date,$row['date_time']);
    }   
    try{    
        $z=count($branch);      
        for ($i=1; $i<count($tpannounce); $i++) { 
            $j=$i;
            --$j;
            mysql_select_db('govtpoly');
            $s="UPDATE placement SET placement_subject=".$tpannounce[$j].",company=".$company[$j].",branches=".$branch[$j].",start_on=".$start[$j].",end_on=".$end[$j].",vanue=".$tpavanue[$j].",documents=".$documents[$j].",date_time=".$date[$j]." WHERE id=".$i;
            mysql_query($s);
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $ex=$e->getMessage();
    }   
    header("location: attendance.php?$ex");
    unset($_POST['submit']);    
 }
```

Comment: Stop using mysql_ functions would be a good start.

Comment: what would be use instead of it (mysql_function).

Comment: Use either PDO or mysqli_ interfaces.  Within these - use prepared statements and bind variables.  As for your problem - looks like your update statement is missing quotes round the values. Try echoing it out before your mysql_query and see how the values need quotes round them.